# Lowering the index of the Riemann curvature tensor in Mathematica

Tags: tensors

I am looking to do some calculations in GR.

For a given metric, I can calculate the affine connection and the Riemann tensor as,

```
affine = Table[(1/2)*
           Sum[(inversemetric[[i, s]])*(D[metric[[s, j]], coord[[k]]] + 
                 D[metric[[s, k]], coord[[j]]] 
                   - D[metric[[j, k]], coord[[s]]]), {s, 1, n}], 
           {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}];

Riemann = 
 Table[D[affine[[i, k, m]], coord[[l]]] - D[affine[[i, k, l]], coord[[m]]] + 
         Sum[affine[[i, s, l]]*affine[[s, k, m]], {s, 1, n}] - 
           Sum[affine[[i, s, m]]*affine[[s, k, l]], {s, 1, n}],
       {i, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}, {l, 1, n}, {m, 1, n}];
```

where `metric` is the metric, `inversemetric` its inverse and `coord` the list of coordinate variables

Now, I want to calculate the Riemann tensor with a lowered index i.e. not $R^{a}_{bcd} $but $R_{abcd}$. The two are related via the covariant metric $R_{abcd} = g_{ae} R^{e}_{bcd}$.

How would I code this up in Mathematica?

Thanks

Comment: You mere have to multiply `inversemetric` or `metric` into the appropriate slot of `Riemann`. Have a look at `TensorProduct` and `TensorContract`.